# Replace For loops with NSPredicate for Core Data call

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I have a 3 level nested for loop:

```
        for (Region *region in group.associatedRegions) {
            for (Boundary *regionBoundary in region.boundaries) {
                for (Boundary *groupBoundary in group.boundaries) {
                    if ([groupBoundary.boundaryID isEqualToNumber:regionBoundary.boundaryID]) {
                        [boundarySet addObject:groupBoundary];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This works. It is fast enough that it doesn't slow the app down.  I don't like it. I have a strong aversion to this level of nesting.

I'm pretty sure I can do the same thing with a `NSPredicate` search instead. My SQL is not that good so I'm not sure where to start.

`Group`, `Region`, and `Boundary` are all `Core Data` `NSManagedObject`s.

Each `Group` has many-to-many relation to boundaries and a 1-to-many relation to regions. Each `Region` has a many-to-many relation to boundaries.

The gist is, a `Group` has a set of boundaries that it can see. A `Region` has a set of boundaries it can see. A `Region` may contain a `Boundary` that the `Group` can not see, so it needs to be excluded.

So, for each `Region`, I need to find the set of boundaries that both `Group` and `Region` can see.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I haven't tested this and I don't even know if it will parse successfully.  But even if it's not exactly what you want, it might provide some ideas for variations of it.  Assuming you are fetching `Boundary` objects, which have a relationship `groups` to the `Groups` entity, which in turn have a relationship `associatedRegions` to the `Regions` entity:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:"SUBQUERY(groups, $G, $G = %@ AND SUBQUERY($G.associatedRegions, $R, SUBQUERY($R.boundaries, $B, self = $B).@count >0).@count >0)).@count > 0", group];
```

What I'm hoping this does is fetch `Boundary` objects where: there is at least one group which 
a) matches the chosen `group` and 
b) has at least one `Region` which has at least one `Boundary` that is the boundary in question.